# How to concatenate strings to variables in Snowflake SQL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

It's possible to use Snowflake [variables](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/session-variables.html#using-variables-in-sql) to determine a source table as follows:

```
set src='some_table';
select count(*) from $src;
```

However, I'm looking for a way to provide a database name as a variable and concatenate that with a table name. Pseudo code:

```
set db='database';
select count(*) from $db.table_name;
```

How can I do this? I'd like to keep `database` and `table_name` separated (so set `dbandtable=database.table_name` is not an option).

Comment: You should rename the question to make it more about querying identifiers :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use the [IDENTIFIER](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/identifier-literal.html) syntax, it's more generic and you can use it in other places, like

```
SELECT * FROM identifier($s_table);
DESC TABLE identifier($s_table);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is way better than using `table`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `select something from $src` doesn't work, so you need to use Snowflake [table literals](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions-table.html) the following way:

```
select something from table($src)
```

The full example of concatenating variables would look like:

```
set s_database='databasename';
set s_table=concat($s_database, '.tablename');
select count(*) from table($s_table);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of combining variables you can also set the default database and schema for the query session [(with `use`)](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/use-database) and then target the table with the [`IDENTIFIER`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/identifier-literal.html) syntax:

```
set table_name='some_table';

use database "DATABASE_NAME";
use schema "SCHEMA_NAME;

SELECT * FROM identifier($table_name);
```